# How to disable syntax errors on ansible template files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ansible

I am using VSCodium with the Docker plugin. When I have a docker-compose file in an ansible
template folder, the linter will show syntax errors whenever it encounters jinja2 template-variables.
The syntax of the docker-compose file is going to be correct after the value of the variable is placed in that file, but until then the syntax is incorrect.
Is there anything I can do about reporting these syntax errors?

here is an example of a docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  reverseproxy:
    image: someimage
    volumes:
    - {{ fooVar }}:/etc/foo
```

VSCode will show you the error
`Unexpected scalar at node end(UNEXPECTED_TOKEN)` on the line containning `- {{ fooVar }}:/etc/foo`

Comment: How about simply quoting the value? => `- "{{ fooVar }}:/etc/foo"` ? Now it's valid yaml, still seen as a jinja2 var to expand by the template module and still good yaml and value after expansion.